# Unable to locate element, only once mouse cursor over it (python, selenium, firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

getting the `Unable to locate element` error while programming in Python with Selenium.

I'm using Firefox and trying to automate to click on a picture by a specific tag.

To guide the browser to the Tag-URL is no problem. But it is not able to find the XPath, only when i have my mouse cursor over it! Means the XPath works for any picture on the loaded site, as long as my mouse cursor is on one of them.

need help.

this is my code so far:

```
//find pic with tag "love"

taglove = driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/love/')

sleep(5)

ChoosenPic = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='_mli86']").click()
```

So it looks like it only activates the XPath once my mouse cursor is over it. If my mouse is not on any of the pictures loaded, it will give me the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you create the variable taglove? It doesn't seem like you use it.

Comment: to use it in future code